# How to fix failed to add navigation dependency android studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, uinavigationcontroller, navigation-drawer

I tried to add a new project using the existing template **Navigation Drawer Activity**. It really works well. However, I accidentally deleted the **mobile_navigation.xml in res/navigation**. Now that every time I tried to open a simple template (even if it is not  Navigation Drawer Activity) I'm getting the below error message.

[image]

[image]

I tried:

1. File/Invalidate Cache/Restart: but it doesn't work
2. I found this `implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5' implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'` to update gradle but I think it is for kotlin. I'm using **Java** on **Android Studio 3.6.2**
3. I even tried creating a new project using templates **Botton Navigation Activity**. However, it is also not working and the same error occurs.
4. I even tried Empty Activity. Then it is weird that I'm getting an `Android resource linking failed` error. And it directs to a .XML (value.xml) of some of my other projects in a different folder which is not even related to this new project. I didn't even open it.

I would appreciate any suggestion to fix this. Thank you!

build.gradle is as below

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```